# What is the proper way to create a collection of singleton fragments in Android?

Tags: java, android, singleton, android-fragments

## Background

I have a ViewPager that will display up to 4 Fragments.  The number available at any given time is dynamic (it could be 1, 2, 3, or 4).  It makes most sense to have these fragments manage themselves.  By that I mean they are singletons.  Rather than creating a new fragment with the new keyword, I've written a 'getInstance(String key)' method which attempts to retrieve the fragment for the specified key from the map, or if it does not exist in the map, creates a new instance, places the fragment in the map with the given key, sets the fragments arguments with a bundle containing that key so the fragment can retrieve it onCreate(), and then returns a new instance of that fragment.

For those who aren't following, here's the code:

```
public class DishListFragment extends ListFragment {
    
    public static final String MENU = "menu";
    
    ...
    
    private static Map<String, DishListFragment> mInstances = new HashMap<String, DishListFragment>();        

    public static DishListFragment getInstance(String menuKey) {
        if (mInstances.containsKey(menuKey))
            return mInstances.get(menuKey);
        
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString(MENU, menuKey);
        DishListFragment dlf = new DishListFragment();
        dlf.setArguments(b);
        mInstances.put(menuKey, dlf);
        return dlf;
        
    }
}
```

*You may have noticed this is not thread safe.*

---

## Walkthrough

OnCreate, my main activity sets its view then spawns an AsyncTask responsible for obtaining data from a server which will populate my DishListFragments.  Meanwhile, the main activity continues on and sets the PagerAdapter.  When the PagerAdapter requests a new DishListFragment, the number is converted into a key dynamically and the value from the DishListFragment.getInstance(key); method is returned.  Initially the content class that is observed by the ListFragments has dummy data so one page always shows up and so there is always one page available for the ViewPager to show.

When the AsyncTask starts, a progress dialog is shown.  When it completes, it dismisses the progress dialog and calls a method in my activity which then sets the data in my content class.  Then a method, refresh(), is called which tells all the DishListFragments in existence to notify their adapters that the dataset has changed.  After that method completes, the ViewPagerAdapter is notified that its dataset has changed.

In my main Activity:

```
public void onRetrieveData(Result result) {
    switch(result.getCode()) {
    case Result.SUCCESS:
    Log.i(UITHREAD, "Menu successfully loaded!");
        /* On SUCCESS the MenuContent class should be given the data and 
         * the adapters notified. */
        mRequestedDate = mPendingDate;
        MenuContent.setMenuData(result.getValue());
        DishListFragment.refresh();
        mMenuPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        
    ...

    }
}
```

And the refresh method in the DishListFragment class:

```
public static void refresh() {
    for (String key : mInstances.keySet()) {
        mInstances.get(key).mListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.d("glic", "DishListFragment: " + key + " refreshed");
    }
    Log.d("glic", "DishListFragments refreshed");
}
```

---

## Problem

The problem is, on a cold start, everything but the frist page is updated.  Further, from my Logcat output, I gather there is only one DishListFragment in my map:

```
10-18 22:11:41.624: I/##############(16802): Menu successfully loaded!
10-18 22:11:41.744: D/glic(16802): DishListFragment: breakfast refreshed 
10-18 22:11:41.744: D/glic(16802): DishListFragments refreshed
10-18 22:11:41.744: D/GLIC(16802): lunch
```

However, my view pager shows 4 pages with the first still containing dummy data.  If I rotate the screen, the first page is updated and displays the correct information.  Also, if I select an item in the dummy list, a details fragment is displayed with real (from the server) information for the position of the item I selected -- even though I only selected a dummy item.

My first thought is I might have two instances of my singleton fragments.  One with a map containing a fragment with the initial dummy data and one containing the real data returned from the server.  I guess this is possible since my singleton is not thread safe.  However, I don't think this should cause any problems.  My DishListFragments do not contain the data they display, they only observe it so regardless of how many instances I might have of the *same* DishListFragment (same being for the same page), they should all observe the same data and should not show different data -- the dummy data is cleared when the new data from the server is parsed and added.

But, two instances of my mInstances map may explain why the view is not updating.  Perhaps the Adapters in only one of the sets of DishListFragments are being notified that their dataset has changed.  According to my Logcat though, *breakfast*, which is my first page and the one that is filled with dummy data, is indeed being notified that its dataset has changed.  Interestingly, the others are not.

---

## Question..

So, as for my original question:  Am I implementing a singleton grouping of Fragments correctly?  If so, what other factors might be causing the weird behavior I'm experiencing.  Thanks in advance (=